# Issue with self-signed certified SSL certificate

Tags: php, openssl, self-signed-certificate

I followed this guide to install certified self-signed SSL certificate on localhost and all works fine in Chrome (no longer any warning, everything is green if https is used on localhost pages):

[Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

However, if I'm running same requests on Ubuntu console via CURL I'm getting **unable to get local issuer certificate**:

```
aherne@home-NUC8i7INH:~$ curl https://localhost
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

This issue reproduces in PHP using certificate from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://localhost");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "cacert.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$body = curl_exec($ch);
if ($body===false) {
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
```

On further verification, issue reproduces using openssl command:

> aherne@home:~$ openssl s_client -connect localhost:443\n
> CONNECTED(00000005)
> depth=0 C = RO, ST = Bucharest, L = Bucharest, O = Home, OU = Home, CN = localhost
> verify error:num=20:**unable to get local issuer certificate**
> verify return:1
> depth=0 C = RO, ST = Bucharest, L = Bucharest, O = Home, OU = Home, CN = localhost
> verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
> verify return:1

---

Is there any way to trick CURL in accepting my certificate as well as my authority that certified it (same way as Chrome)? **Making cURL skip SSL verification is a non-solution!**

Answer (score 1):

I believe the possible ways to have curl accept your certificate authority are located here:

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

I suspect this would be the easiest approach:

> If you're using the curl command line tool, you can specify your own CA cert file by setting the environment variable CURL_CA_BUNDLE to the path of your choice.